# MAMP Pro Directory listings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mamp

On my local dev environment, I want to allow directory listings where there is no index file in the directory.

This works fine until I add my .htaccess (for removing index.php on my CMS) file which looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(_app) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(_config) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(_content) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).yml$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).yaml$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.git+ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

I get a 403 forbidden error.

Any ideas on how to override?

Comment: You get a 403 error when trying to access what, everything? You should describe in detail what are to trying to protect, because from the rules is hard to guess. ¿Is there a file like `file_app` or is that a directory? If so, where is it in the path?  What about `_config` and `_content`?

Comment: no, accessing http://domain.dev and the pages generated by my CMS work fine. What I want though is to be able to see what's inside /css

Comment: Try to add this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css` before `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. Just a guess.

Comment: I want it for any directory though, not just css and I don't want to have to add each dir manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi got to have it working just by turning on INDEXES at Extended Tab, Options for  directive.

[image: MAMP PRO HOSTS PANEL]